# Tilting a UIView in Y and Z-direction

Tags: uiview, calayer, catransform3d, catransform3drotate

My graphics is such that in order for my view content to properly align with graphics, it needs to rotate in depth ie along z-axis. Maybe 5-10 degrees along z, and negative 5-10 degrees along y.

Currently I use this: (argView is my imageview)

```
[argView.layer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.5, 1, -1, 0)];
```

However this gives me very skewed image - definitely not what I want, but I don't know what I should be supplying there.

I began by reading apple docs but there are just so many functions I am getting confused.
If someone has any good guide that will make it very easy for me, great.
If someone can point to where this exact thing has been done, greater.

Comment: Would anyone know where to begin reading about z axis rotation, at the very least?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is CATransform3DMakeRotation used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576534/how-is-catransform3dmakerotation-used)