# iphone : How to implement the page flip effect without curl?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, core-graphics, page-flipping

I need to implement the page flip effect in an iOS app. But the the effect should not curl the page like it does with UIPageViewController and some other third party libraries that I have checked . The page should be a rigid one as its the page of a greeting card and not the book. I have to implement something as in the below image.

[image]

I would really appreciate if any one could provide any suggestions or sample code.

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: You should look at http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/tag/catransform3d/ for more information

Comment: can you tell me the name of the app where you have seen this animation

Comment: @Leena Its not in the appstore yet. I am working on this.

Comment: @Micazeve and Sharon Nathaniel , Thanks for the links . I checked the links but could not figure out how to modify these libraries as per my need. They all fold the page from the center. But in my case it has to be just a page flip from the left edge of the page. Its a simple two page greeting card actually.

Comment: You need to look at how Core Foundation makes 3D Transformations. The answer to this post has all the links you should need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576534/how-is-catransform3dmakerotation-used

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:
UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be helpful for you.

```
-(void) animateMe:(UIViewAnimationTransition)style
{
   [self playCardSound];
   [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
   [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
   [UIView setAnimationTransition: style forView:self.view cache:YES];
   [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Call it like:

```
[self animateMe:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft];
[self animateMe:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight];
```